# Python: Double colon in the class name

Tags: python

I have encountered the following thing when debugging code in Python:

```
<ROOT.cool::IDatabase object at 0xbc88680>
```

What the double colon means, and why would I need them?

Comment: What object is this (what library)? The `repr()` of an object is decided by that object, this appears to be a convention for some project that has some kind of interface setup.

Comment: To make it even more explicit: Colons are not valid in [Python identifiers](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

Comment: What do you mean "why would I need them?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me it seems like a python wrapper over a C++ class function and therefore the `::`

And like Lattyware said it's just the return of a call to `__repr__()` of a python object.

You could very well make you own to be sure:

```
class Foo():
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Foo.bar:::qux::::kludge object at %s>" %hex(id(self))
```

Therefore you don't need to worry about the `::`, but it is the object itself that you might need to aid your debugging.